# Wieso ist namens ein Adverb?

Tags: adverb

namens = mit [dem] Namen

Bezieht sich im Folgendem "namens" nicht auf Mann? Warum ist es dann ein Adverb gemäss [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/namens_genannt)?

> ein Mann namens Maier

Man könnte auch schreiben:

> ein Mann mit dem Namen Maier

In [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverb#Nicht-adverbiale_Verwendungen_von_Adverbien) findet sich ein ähnliches Beispiel mit "dort".

[Das Auto *dort*] ist meins.

Answer (score 2):

Meines Wissens liefert das Wörterbuch des Duden keinerlei Erklärung dazu, wie Wortarten unterschieden werden. Man kann aber folgende Vermutung anstellen.

Für die Einordnung als Adverb spricht die Bildung mit *-s* wie bei *tags, flugs* usw.

Gegen die Einordnung als Präposition spricht, daß *namens* keinen bestimmten Kasus fordert. Stattdessen steht das angeschlossene Nomen immer im Kasus des Bezugsausdrucks oder ist kasuslos.

> Am Meppener Marktplatz erinnert eine Gedenktafel **an einen** Ehrenbürger namens **Herrn** Riedemann [Akk.], dem die Erfindung des Öltankers zu verdanken sein soll. (*SZ*, 13.06.1994, via [COSMAS II](https://www.ids-mannheim.de/cosmas2/))
>
> Ich habe **mit einem** Angestellten namens **Herrn** Maier [Dat.] gesprochen.
>
> Ich habe **mit einem** Angestellten namens **Herr** Maier [kasuslos] gesprochen.
>
> Ein Angestellter namens Herr Maier hat mit mir gesprochen.

Es bleibt beachtenswert, daß *namens* im Gegensatz zu anderen Adverbien nicht allein stehen kann. In der Linguistik nennt man solche Wörter, die sich idiosynkratisch verhalten, auch Einzelgänger.

Schließlich soll noch erwähnt werden, daß es auch eine Präposition *namens* gibt; diese fordert den Genitiv.

> Herr Bramslöff-Hamburg beantragt **namens des Nautischen Vereins** in Hamburg Vertagung der Beschlußfassung über die Anträge […] (*Berliner Tageblatt*, 03.03.1904, aus dem [DWDS-Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/r))

**Nachtrag**: Wenn es darum gehen sollte, ob Adverbien sich überhaupt auf Nomen beziehen können, so finde ich das ganz selbstverständlich.

> Das Treffen gestern war mal wieder der Hammer.
> Die Zeit dort war für mich echt überwältigend.
> Bei unserer Ankunft nachts war ich leicht geschockt.

Das Besondere bei *namens* ist, daß es nicht allein stehen kann.

Comment: Wikipedia sagt, dass es keine mehrheitliche vertretende Definition von "Adverb" gibt, so dass es eher als "sonstige" daherkommt. Das dürfte erklären, warum auch der Duden sich ausschweigt.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm "Adverb" hat durchaus manchmal den Charakter einer Restklasse, aber in diesem Fall findet man immerhin ein Argument pro Adverb und eines contra Präposition.

Comment: Je mehr ich über "namens + Kausus von außen" nachdenke, desto verwirrter bin ich. Was wäre mit _mit einem Angestellten mit dem Namen Herrn Maier_? Das ist auch irgendwie akzeptabel, aber bei genauerer Analyse kommt es mir immer ungrammatischer vor... ist das nur eine fehlgeleitete Analogie? (Dem Rest deiner Antwort stimme ich aber sehr zu.)